# Why is EF cascade delete not working on 0 to 1 relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following table defined through code-first:

```
public class Action 
{
    public int ActionId { get; set; }

    public int? EmailMessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailMessage EmailMessage { get; set; }
}

public class EmailMessage
{
    public int EmailMessageId { get; set; }

    public string Content { get;set;
}
```

When an action is created with a corresponding EmailMessage, deleting the action doesn't remove the entry in EmailMessage.  It seems EF only creates a cascade delete on 1-many relationships.  In this case the relationship is 0 or 1 relationship which has no cascade delete set by default.

I then added the fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Action>()
  .HasOptional(x =>x.EmailMessage)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(x=>x.EmailMessageId)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Which seems to correctly set the CASCADE DELETE when viewing the schema in Management Studio. But when I remove the row from Action manually from the db, the row in EmailMessage remains.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?
I thought I might be getting somewhere when I used 'WithOptionalDependent()' in the configuration.  However when I looked at the schema, it had introduced "EmailMessage_EmailMessageId", when I already had EmailMessageId in the table?

Can anyone advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cascade delete is designed to remove the *child* when the *parent* is deleted, not the other way around.  In this case, the Action is the child associated with the foreign-key of the EmailMessage parent.  So deleting the Action will not affect the EmailMessage, but deleting the EmailMessage should cascade delete to the Action.

Comment: Ah ok. Conceptually though, it feels like EmailMessage is a child because the navigation property is pointing from Action to EmailMessage.  If the relationship was 0-many with the EmailMessage being a Collection inside Action, then wouldn't this then be a child?

Comment: Correct, but then the `EmailMessage` would have an `ActionId` field with a foreign key pointing to the `Action`. In the end the database doesn't know how you configured your POCO models, it only knows the primary/foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized when using "contextName.Entry(parentStudySession).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;" to delete some parent with a few children..I talk for EF 6.3, EF doesnt't delete the children for us, even didn't delete the parent itself even though we have got cascading on delete constraint. Instead, it gives an error "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not ... "

Instead, when I use "contextName.StudySession.Remove(parentStudySession);" ,
EF 6.3 successfully deletes the PARENT and the CHILDREN... I have cascade on delete constraint. 
*T.Adakoğlu*